# Swagger UI generating wrong Curl command

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

Swagger UI generating wrong Curl command as pasted below and due to this query string truncating

curl -X GET http://domain:8080/v1/endpoint?access_token=affsfafasfa&type=1  -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "content-type: application/json"

the correct Curl command should be like this

curl -X GET    'http://domain:8080/v1/endpoint?access_token=affsfafasfa&type=1'    -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "content-type: application/json"

the difference between above two command is quote around http url . So please tell me how to achieve this in swagger ui ?

Comment: Which version of Swagger UI, 2.x or the new 3.x?

Comment: @Helen Swagger UI version 3.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an bug in swagger ui version 3.0.2 and swagger support team has fixed this bug now https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2839

Answer (score 2):

I guess you found [a bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2839) in the new version. The very latest code already contains a fix for it.